# Webpack me da problema al ejecutarlo desde npm

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, npm, webpack

Tengo un repo en github y quiero hacerle un deploy con heroku configure la app en el sitio de este ultimo y cuando intento hacr un deploy me lanza el siguiente error:

> The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type boolean at assertPath

Me di cuenta que el intenta ejecutar este comando:

`webpack -mode production`

Por tanto modifique mi `package.json` localmente y añadí un script que ejecutase ese mismo comando y cual fue mi sorpresa darme cuenta de que localmente daba el mismo error. He estado buscando en Internet por una cantidad de páginas y ninguna solución parece funcionar. Aquí les dejo el código de los archivos implicados

**package.json:**

```
  {
    "name": "react-todo-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Initial react js ToDo app",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
      "build": "webpack -mode production",
      "test": "jest",
      "heroku-postbuild": "webpack -mode production"
    },
    "jest": {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
        "^.+\\.(css|sass)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
      }
    },
    "engines": {
      "npm": "6.4.1",
      "node": "10.15.1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.18",
      "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.2",
      "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
      "@types/jest": "^24.0.12",
      "classnames": "^2.2.6",
      "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
      "react": "^16.8.6",
      "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
      "sinon": "^7.3.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
      "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
      "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
      "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
      "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
      "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
      "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
      "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
      "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
      "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.12.1",
      "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
      "jest": "^24.8.0",
      "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
      "webpack": "^4.33.0",
      "webpack-cli": "^3.3.3",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
    }
 }
```

**Webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const HWP = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.js'),
    output: {
        filename: 'build.js',
        publicPath: '',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        {
                            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
                        }
                    ]
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HWP(
            { template: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.htm') }
        )
    ]
}
```

Si uso `npm run start` Todo funciona perfectamente, es decir problemas con la configuración de webpack o los módulos instalados no parece ser. Cualquier ayuda sera bienvenida.

Estoy usando Windows 10 64bits y las versiones de node y npm estan en la entrada **engines** de mi **pacakage.json**

El mensaje de error mas completo lo dejo por si ayuda en algo:
[image: Error]

Comment: Es un error de tipeo, las opciones de configuración de CLI para Webpack usan doble dash (`--`), además debes realizar la asignación del modo a la variable de configuración, deberías poner: `wepack --mode=production`. Otra opción es que agregues a tu `webpack.config.js` lo siguiente: `mode: 'production'`. Puedes consultar la [documentación oficial](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/). Saludos

Comment: Lo mas probable es que se deba a una incompatiblidad de alguna dependencia de webpack con esa version de npm

Comment: Pon tu comentario como respuesta tuve que hacerle unos cambios pero en resumen acertastes

Comment: No hace falta la verdad, es un error de tipeo o de configuración, no es un problema de programación, creo que puedes eliminar esta pregunta ya que realmente no está relacionada con [es.so]. Saludos